# xgboost and gridsearchcv in python

Tags: python, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I have question about this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrJP9FLV3FE).

The author is doing hyper parameter tuning. The first window shows different values of hyperparameters

[image]

Then he initializes `gridsearchcv` and mentions `cv=3` and `scoring='roc_auc'`
[image]

then he fits `gridsearchcv` and uses `eval_set` and `eval_metric='auc'`
[image]

1. what is the purpose using `cv` and `eval_set` both? shouldn't we use just one of them? how they are used along with `scoring='roc_auc' and eval_metric='auc'`
2. is there a better way to do hyper parameter tuning using `gridsearchcv`? please suggest or provide a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `GridSearchCV` performs cv for hyperparameter tuning using only training data. Since `refit=True` by default, the best fit is then validated on the eval set provided (a true test score).
   You can use any metric to perform cv and testing. However, it would be odd to use a different metric for cv hyperparameter optimization and testing phases. So, the same metric is used. If you are wondering about the slightly different metric naming, I think it's just because `xgboost` is a sklearn-interface-compliant package, but it's not being developed by the same guys from `sklearn`. They should do both the same thing (area under the curve of receiving operator for predictions). Take a look at the sklearn docs: [auc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html#sklearn.metrics.auc) and [roc_auc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score).
2. I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: `early_stopping_rounds=10` - when that is used? on test data or when we find best parameters? and for `gridsearchcv` how is model going to determine when to stop? for example lets say it is using some combination of hyper parameters , how many trees it is going to build?

Comment: Yes, if the cv testing score does not improve over 10 consecutive cv hyperparameter round choices, training should terminate earlier.
Basically, your cv is performed for each hyperparameter set chosen (randomly with grid). If the cv testing mse is stationary for over 10 rounds, it stops.

Comment: I would highly suggest to use the ``verbose`` flag to have live logs while fitting

Comment: if we remove `eval_set` and `eval_metric` would it affect model output at all? is early stopping also used on `eval_set`?

Comment: how would the best best hyper parameters be chosen - based upon results of `cv` (only training data) or based upon performance on `eval_set`?

Comment: I really don't think  ``early_stopping`` mechanisms makes sense for ``GridSearchCV`` in the first place, since there is probably no correlation between different hyperparameter sets. However, digging into the code, seems that including an ``eval_set`` will use just that set for CV testing phase (using a hold-out-like CV) which is not true k-fold CV (used by default).

Comment: do you have any better example of `gridsearchcv` and `xgboost`? thanks